# USB over IP - Azure VM - On Premise USB

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, usbserial, intel-edison

I'd like to access a set (4-8) on premise microcontrollers over USB from Azure VM (Windows 10).
It must support USB to serial, since the VM development environment should be able to upload the compiled firmware onto the on premise microcontroller, like Intel Edison and Telnet or SSH into it as well.
It could be a software or hardware solution. What my options are?